# How to automatically load classes without debug_backtrace()

Tags: php, backtrace, autoloader, spl-autoload-register, php-include

I've written a little system that automatically loads classes from the same directory in which it's located the file who require that class.

```
<?php

function load_class($class_name, $backtrace_level = 1)
{
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, $backtrace_level);
    $backtrace = array_pop($backtrace);

    include_once dirname($backtrace['file']) . '/' . $class_name . '.php';
}

function class_autoloader($class_name)
{
    load_class($class_name, 3);
}

spl_autoload_register('class_autoloader');
```

Now i can include classes in two ways:

1. Through spl_autoload_register():

   - `$test_obj = new Base_class;` or `Test_class extends Base_class`
2. Through load_class():

   - `load_class('Base_class');`

In both cases the `Base_class` should be included from the same directory in which it was required.

E.g.

File **/application/models/Extendend_class.php**

```
<?php

class Extended_class extends Base_class {
    /* class code... */
}
```

should automatically include **/application/models/Base_class.php**

[Some say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346703/php-debug-backtrace-in-production-code) (and I quite agree with them) that using debug_backtrace() in production code is a poor practice, so the question is: there is a way to achieve a *similar* behaviour without that function?

Thanks in advance.

*P.S.*
[This](http://pastebin.com/jzSCj6V7) is the actual script I'm working on.

### Update

I tried as suggested with an empty try - catch and it works! It might not be the "cleanest" solution, but it works...

```
function load_class($class_name, $backtrace_level = 0)
{
    try 
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {}

    $backtrace = $e->getTrace();
    $backtrace = $backtrace[$backtrace_level];

    include_once dirname($backtrace['file']) . '/' . $class_name . '.php';
}

function class_autoloader($class_name)
{
    load_class($class_name, 2);
}

spl_autoload_register('class_autoloader');
```

### Update 2

The best way to autoload classes is probably through namespaces.
[This](http://pastebin.com/A8cYp9CM) is a sample implementation.

Comment: You could throw an exception in a empty `try..catch` and use `$e->getTrace()`, but then you're throwing a useless exception which isn't pretty either. See [Exception](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php).

Answer (score 1):

exactly how @h2ooooooo he comment you can try to catch the exception and know the error from where is comeing

```
function load_class($class_name, $backtrace_level = 1)
{
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, $backtrace_level);
    $backtrace = array_pop($backtrace);
    if (file_exists(dirname($backtrace['file']) . '/' . $class_name . '.php')) {
        include_once  dirname($backtrace['file']) . '/' . $class_name . '.php';
    } else {
        exit ('The file ' .dirname($backtrace['file']) . '/' . $class_name . '.php' . ' is missing in     the path file.');
}

}

function class_autoloader($class_name)
{
    load_class($class_name, 3);
}

spl_autoload_register('class_autoloader');
```