# What’s the purpose of the $relation parameter in HasRelationships->belongsTo()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

So I was wandering in the source code of the `HasRelationsShips` trait and found that there’s this `$relation` parameter in methods like [`belongsTo`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L194) that doesn’t show up in Laravel’s doc examples and by the looks of it serves only to debug purposes. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not for debug purposes, it is so you can define the relation name explicitly. Without that argument the BelongsTo will implicitly use the calling method name as the 'relation' name, example:

```
function user() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This will use a backtrace to know that the `belongsTo` was called from a method named `user`. So it will know the relation is `user`. Since we didn't explicitly tell it any foreign key it will use the relation, `user`, to build the foreign key: `$relation .'_'. $relatedInstance->getKeyName()` which would build `user_id`. This relation name is also used so that other relationship functionality knows what the name of the relationship method is on this model for this relationship, such as the `associate` and `disassociate` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on lagbox's answer, the use of a backtrace happens in [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelations::guessBelongsToRelation()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v9.22.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L335) and looks like this:

```php
protected function guessBelongsToRelation()
{
    [$one, $two, $caller] = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 3);
    return $caller['function'];
}
```

The use of `debug_backtrace()` is [controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346703/php-debug-backtrace-in-production-code-to-get-information-about-calling-method) – and I'm not a big fan of micro-optimizations generally – but in this case with modern PHP it's very easy to skip the function altogether.

All my belongs-to relationships are simply defined like this, using a named argument and magic constant:

```php
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, relation: __FUNCTION__);
}
```